# Five forms of inscribe a figure within another

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you help me to find five different forms of inscribing a cube within dodecahedron?, I think there must be a better way to do this without staying a long time in front of the paper drawing (I have done this and I cant get the result)

Thanks a lot for the help in advance.

Comment: By inscribing, I imagine we're putting the $8$ vertices of the cube on the boundary (faces, edges) of a dodecahedron? Have you found any way to inscribe the cube?

Comment: I have found a way, linking the middle points of each penthagon

Comment: But I have to find four more jajajajaj

Comment: Well I have drawn my idea and it does not work :(

Comment: Yeah, it's an odd one; the $12$ faces don't lend themselves to placing $8$ vertices uniformly, but for some reason, the $20$ vertices, partitioned properly, do. See [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_of_five_cubes).

Comment: well there is one :) hurray, how can I do it for the other four? jajajajja thanks  a lot